# Regex to match text with only emoticons and no other text

Tags: javascript, emoji, emoticons

I have this regex for detecting if a string contains any emoticons:

```
/(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g
```

But how can I detect if a string ONLY contains emoticons and not any other standard text? I tried to enclose the above in `[]` without success. Am using javascript.

Comment: use start and end qualifiers

Comment: Got me on right track. I just needed to add  `^` to beginning and `{1,3}` to end to match only 1,2, or 3 emoji-only messages.

Answer (score 2):

Remove anything that matches the pattern and see if there's anything left. Consider using `trim()` as well if you think there might be unwanted whitespace.

```js
var pattern = /(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g;

var str2 = 'ℹ〰';
var str1 = 'ℹ〰asdfasd';

var isOnlyEmojis = str=>str.replace(pattern, '') === "";

console.log(isOnlyEmojis(str2) ? "It's just emojis!" : "Has real text..")
console.log(isOnlyEmojis(str1) ? "It's just emojis!" : "Has real text..")
```