# Is there a way to check if a string in JS is one single emoji?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, unicode, emoji

> The question is simple: I have a string `str`, how do I check if `str` is one single emoji, and nothing else? Additionally I would prefer not using another library.
>
> Match `""`, `"⛹‍♂️"`, `"3️⃣"` but not `"a"`, `""`, `""`

I'm having trouble finding a solution but here are some things I've tried so far:

---

### Attempted Solution 1 - Play around lengths and `...` operator

I learned that emojis occupy more than one byte, some even occupy 4 bytes, or more... and we can measure that via the string's `length` property:

```js
console.log("".length); // 2
console.log("️".length); // 3
console.log("⛹‍♂️".length); // 6
```

Then I found out that the `...` operator takes this into account and correctly separates emojis in the array - I could then see the resulting array's `length` property and detect if they were different.

```js
str = "⛹‍♂️";
if (str.length !== [...str].length) {
  // is emoji?
} else {
  // is not emoji
}
```

But this doesn't check for other multi-byte characters such as  whose length is 2. Plus some emojis were still getting separated in a weird.

---

### Attempted Solution 2 - Regex, regular expressions

Of course regex would be a thing to look into but I've yet to find a viable solution.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55561707/10943586)'s regex `\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff]` works perfectly fine to detect if a string has any emojis, but applied to my situation it produces a lot of problems. Here are my tests:

**Part A - Without start/end of string regex (`^` and `$`)**

- **2A.1** `str.match(regex)` is very inconsistent, it breaks down some emojis and some other unusable. I don't see a way to find out if it even contains non-emoji characters or if it contains more than one emoji:

```js
let regex = /(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/;

console.log("5️⃣".match(regex)); // [ '⃣', '⃣', index: 2, input: '5️⃣' ]
console.log("".match(regex)); // [ '', '', index: 0, input: '' ]
console.log("️️".match(regex)); // [ '', '', index: 0, input: '️️' ]
console.log("a⛅".match(regex)); // [ '⛅', '⛅', index: 1, input: 'a⛅' ]
```

- **2A.2** `regex.test(str)` returns true whenever an emoji is included in the string, which isn't the behaviour I'm looking for:

```js
let regex = /(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/;

console.log(regex.test("5️⃣")); // true - correct
console.log(regex.test("a")); // false - correct
console.log(regex.test("️️")); // true - should be false
console.log(regex.test("hello ⛅!")); // true - should be false
```

**Part B - With start/end of string regex (`^` and `$`)**

- **2B.1** `str.match(regex)` returns `null` on certain emojis for some reason. I have no clue why but I'm assuming it has some relation as to why `str.match(regex)` would break down these emojis in Part A:

```js
let regex = /^(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])$/;

console.log("5️⃣".match(regex)); // null
console.log("".match(regex)); // [ '', '', index: 0, input: '' ]
console.log("️".match(regex)); // null
console.log("⛅".match(regex)); // [ '⛅', '⛅', index: 1, input: 'a⛅' ]
console.log("".match(regex)); // null
```

- **2B.2** `regex.test(str)` will return `false` on the same emojis where it would return `null` on `str.match(regex)`:

```js
let regex = /^(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])$/;

console.log(regex.test("5️⃣")); // false - should be true
console.log(regex.test("")); // true - correct
console.log(regex.test("️")); // false - should be true
console.log(regex.test("⛅")); // true - correct
console.log(regex.test("")); // false - correct
```

**Part C - Other regular expressions**

- I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48267422/10943586) but it gives similar inconsistencies, although not the same `/(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g`:

```js
let regex = /^(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])$/g

console.log(regex.test("5️⃣")); // true - correct
console.log(regex.test("")); // false - should be true
console.log(regex.test("️")); // false - should be true
console.log(regex.test("⛅")); // true - correct
console.log(regex.test("")); // false - correct
```

- Also this breaks horribly (second test changes based on first test?)

```js
let regex = /^(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])$/g

console.log(regex.test("⛹‍♂️")); // false
console.log(regex.test("⛅")); // true
```

```
let regex = /^(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01\uddff]|\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50\ude3a]|\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])$/g;

console.log(regex.test("⛹")); // true
console.log(regex.test("⛅")); // false
```

---

Is there a way around all this emoji/unicode/regex mess? Are libraries/apis the only way? How do they do it?

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/dQEURi/1

Comment: I personally think maintaining a regex is not a very good idea, unless you're generating it from the [unicode specification](https://unicode.org/Public/emoji/). There are already libraries that are doing that though. See [emoji-regex](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/emoji-regex) and [emoji.json](https://github.com/amio/emoji.json).

Comment: Thank you Wiktor Stribiżew, that regex works perfectly! May I know how or where you got this from?

Comment: I had looked into emoji-regex but figured I didn't want another library just for this task. emoji.json seems very simple though and I might use it instead of regex

Comment: There's a time and a place for libraries. IMHO this is one of them. The cost of maintaining a dependency with its versions and and file size seems more than outweighed by having someone else solving this very complex problem for you.

Comment: Re: "how do they do it" the library that Daniel Vickers linked refers to: https://unicode.org/reports/tr29/#Default_Grapheme_Cluster_Table

Comment: tempted to close as dup of https://stackoverflow.com/q/18862256/11107541 except for daxim's answer, which I haven't verified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using this library: https://github.com/foliojs/grapheme-breaker try this:

```
var str = "⛹‍♂️";
var Grapheme = require('grapheme-splitter');
var splitter = new Grapheme();
console.log(splitter.splitGraphemes(str).length);
```

and the length should return 1.

Comment: This library is awesome, but it's been inactive for a year now, however it's inspired by https://github.com/foliojs/grapheme-breaker which has been active very recently :) (i deleted my old comment cuz it had the wrong link)

Comment: Thanks for that, I've updated the link in my answer as well.

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are specified in UAX #51. The property `\p{Emoji}` should work, but doesn't.

Do it the hard way. Parse [`emoji-*.txt`](https://www.unicode.org/Public/emoji/12.1/):

```
perl -C -lne'
    if (my ($c) = $_ =~ /^((?:(?:[[:xdigit:]]+ )|[[:xdigit:]]+\.\.)[[:xdigit:]]+)/) {
        if ($c =~ /\.\./) { # ranges
             my ($f, $t) = map { hex } split /\.\./, $c;
             print for map { chr } $f..$t;
        } else { # sequences
             print join "", map { chr hex } split /\s+/, $c;
        }
    }
' emoji-*.txt
```

This gives us a newline separated list of all emojis. Using Regexp::Assemble::Compressed, the result is

```
/^(?:[\u{23EB}\u{23EC}\u{23F0}\u{2607}-\u{260D}\u{260F}\u{2610}\u{2616}\u{2617}\u{2619}-\u{261C}\u{261E}\u{261F}\u{2624}\u{2625}\u{2627}-\u{2629}\u{262B}-\u{262D}\u{2630}-\u{2637}\u{263B}-\u{263F}\u{2643}-\u{2647}\u{2654}-\u{265E}\u{2661}\u{2662}\u{2669}-\u{267A}\u{267C}\u{267D}\u{2680}-\u{2685}\u{2690}\u{2691}\u{269D}-\u{269F}\u{26A2}-\u{26A9}\u{26AC}-\u{26AF}\u{26B2}-\u{26BC}\u{26BF}-\u{26C3}\u{26C6}\u{26C7}\u{26C9}-\u{26CE}\u{26D5}-\u{26E8}\u{26EB}-\u{26EF}\u{26FB}\u{26FC}\u{26FE}-\u{2701}\u{2703}\u{2704}\u{2710}\u{2711}\u{2754}\u{2755}\u{2765}-\u{2767}\u{2795}-\u{2797}\u{1F000}-\u{1F003}\u{1F005}-\u{1F0CE}\u{1F0D0}-\u{1F0FF}\u{1F10D}-\u{1F10F}\u{1F16C}-\u{1F16F}\u{1F191}-\u{1F19A}\u{1F1AD}-\u{1F1E5}\u{1F201}\u{1F203}-\u{1F20F}\u{1F232}-\u{1F236}\u{1F238}-\u{1F23A}\u{1F23C}-\u{1F23F}\u{1F249}-\u{1F30C}\u{1F310}-\u{1F314}\u{1F316}-\u{1F31B}\u{1F31D}-\u{1F320}\u{1F322}\u{1F323}\u{1F32D}-\u{1F335}\u{1F337}-\u{1F377}\u{1F379}-\u{1F37C}\u{1F37E}-\u{1F384}\u{1F386}-\u{1F392}\u{1F394}\u{1F395}\u{1F39C}\u{1F39D}\u{1F3A0}-\u{1F3A6}\u{1F3A8}-\u{1F3AB}\u{1F3AF}-\u{1F3C1}\u{1F3C5}\u{1F3C8}\u{1F3C9}\u{1F3CF}-\u{1F3D3}\u{1F3E1}-\u{1F3EC}\u{1F3EE}-\u{1F3F2}\u{1F3F8}-\u{1F407}\u{1F409}-\u{1F414}\u{1F416}-\u{1F41E}\u{1F420}-\u{1F425}\u{1F427}-\u{1F43E}\u{1F440}\u{1F444}\u{1F445}\u{1F451}\u{1F452}\u{1F454}-\u{1F465}\u{1F479}-\u{1F47B}\u{1F47E}-\u{1F480}\u{1F484}\u{1F488}-\u{1F4A2}\u{1F4A4}-\u{1F4A9}\u{1F4AB}-\u{1F4AF}\u{1F4B1}\u{1F4B2}\u{1F4B4}-\u{1F4BA}\u{1F4BC}-\u{1F4BE}\u{1F4C0}-\u{1F4CA}\u{1F4CC}-\u{1F4D9}\u{1F4DB}-\u{1F4DE}\u{1F4E0}-\u{1F4E3}\u{1F4E7}-\u{1F4E9}\u{1F4EE}-\u{1F4F6}\u{1F4F8}\u{1F4FC}\u{1F4FF}-\u{1F507}\u{1F509}-\u{1F50C}\u{1F50E}-\u{1F511}\u{1F514}-\u{1F53D}\u{1F546}-\u{1F548}\u{1F54B}-\u{1F54E}\u{1F568}-\u{1F56E}\u{1F571}\u{1F572}\u{1F57B}-\u{1F586}\u{1F588}\u{1F589}\u{1F58E}\u{1F58F}\u{1F591}-\u{1F594}\u{1F597}-\u{1F5A3}\u{1F5A6}\u{1F5A7}\u{1F5A9}-\u{1F5B0}\u{1F5B3}-\u{1F5BB}\u{1F5BD}-\u{1F5C1}\u{1F5C5}-\u{1F5D0}\u{1F5D4}-\u{1F5DB}\u{1F5DF}\u{1F5E0}\u{1F5E4}-\u{1F5E7}\u{1F5E9}-\u{1F5EE}\u{1F5F0}-\u{1F5F2}\u{1F5F4}-\u{1F5F9}\u{1F5FB}-\u{1F60F}\u{1F611}-\u{1F644}\u{1F648}-\u{1F64A}\u{1F680}-\u{1F686}\u{1F688}-\u{1F68C}\u{1F68E}-\u{1F690}\u{1F692}\u{1F693}\u{1F695}-\u{1F697}\u{1F699}-\u{1F6A2}\u{1F6A4}-\u{1F6AC}\u{1F6AE}-\u{1F6B1}\u{1F6B3}\u{1F6B7}\u{1F6B8}\u{1F6BB}\u{1F6BD}-\u{1F6BF}\u{1F6C1}-\u{1F6CA}\u{1F6D0}-\u{1F6D4}\u{1F6D6}-\u{1F6DF}\u{1F6E6}-\u{1F6E8}\u{1F6EB}-\u{1F6EF}\u{1F6F1}\u{1F6F2}\u{1F6F4}-\u{1F6F8}\u{1F6FB}-\u{1F6FF}\u{1F774}-\u{1F77F}\u{1F7D5}-\u{1F7FF}\u{1F80C}-\u{1F80F}\u{1F848}-\u{1F84F}\u{1F85A}-\u{1F85F}\u{1F888}-\u{1F88F}\u{1F8AE}-\u{1F8FF}\u{1F90D}\u{1F90E}\u{1F910}-\u{1F917}\u{1F91D}\u{1F920}-\u{1F925}\u{1F927}-\u{1F92F}\u{1F93A}\u{1F940}-\u{1F945}\u{1F947}-\u{1F94B}\u{1F94D}-\u{1F970}\u{1F973}-\u{1F979}\u{1F97C}-\u{1F9B4}\u{1F9B7}\u{1F9BA}\u{1F9BC}-\u{1F9BF}\u{1F9C1}-\u{1F9CC}\u{1F9D0}\u{1F9E0}-\u{1FFFD}\u{E0020}-\u{E007F}]|\u{1F1F2}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1E7}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E9}-\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1F8}[\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FD}-\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1E8}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EB}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FA}-\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1EC}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E7}\u{1F1E9}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}]?|\u{1F1E6}[\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FD}\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1F9}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1E9}\u{1F1EB}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1EF}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1F5}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EA}-\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F0}-\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}]?|\u{1F1F3}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}-\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F1}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1EE}[\u{1F1E8}-\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F1}-\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F6}-\u{1F1F9}]?|\u{1F1F0}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}-\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F5}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1FC}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1F1}[\u{1F1E6}-\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FB}\u{1F1FE}]?|\u{1F1EA}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1ED}\u{1F1F7}-\u{1F1FA}]?|\u{26F9}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F3C4}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F3CA}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F3CB}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F3CC}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F575}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{270C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{270D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F1E9}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EF}\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1FA}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FE}\u{1F1FF}]?|\u{1F1FB}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1E8}\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1EC}\u{1F1EE}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1FA}]?|\u{1F3C2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F442}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F446}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F447}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F448}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F449}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F44D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F44E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F574}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{261D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|\u{1F1EB}[\u{1F1EE}-\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F7}]?|\u{1F1ED}[\u{1F1F0}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F3}\u{1F1F7}\u{1F1F9}\u{1F1FA}]?|\u{1F3C3}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F468}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F469}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F46E}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F471}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F473}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F477}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F481}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F482}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F486}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F487}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F590}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|\u{1F645}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F646}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F647}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F64B}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F64D}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F64E}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F6A3}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F6B4}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F6B5}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F6B6}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F926}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F937}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F938}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F939}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F93D}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F93E}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9B8}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9B9}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9CD}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9CE}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9CF}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D1}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D6}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D7}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D8}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D9}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9DA}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9DB}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9DC}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9DD}[\u{200D}\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{270A}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{270B}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F1F7}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F8}\u{1F1FA}\u{1F1FC}]?|\u{1F385}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F3C7}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F443}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F44A}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F44B}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F44C}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F44F}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F450}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F466}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F467}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F46B}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F46C}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F46D}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F470}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F472}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F474}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F475}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F476}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F478}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F47C}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F483}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F485}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F4AA}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F595}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F596}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F64C}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F64F}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F6C0}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F6CC}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F90F}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F918}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F919}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F91A}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F91B}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F91C}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F91E}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F931}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F932}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F933}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F934}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F935}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F936}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9B5}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9B6}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9BB}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D2}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D3}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D4}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F9D5}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]?|\u{1F1EF}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F5}]?|\u{1F57A}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|\u{1F91F}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|\u{1F930}[\u{1F3FB}-\u{1F3FF}]|0[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|1[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|2[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|3[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|4[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|5[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|6[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|7[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|8[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|9[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\\*[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F1FF}[\u{1F1E6}\u{1F1F2}\u{1F1FC}]?|\u{1F3F3}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F415}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F441}[\u{200D}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|#[\u{20E3}\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2194}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2195}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2196}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2197}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2198}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2199}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{21A9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{21AA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{231A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{231B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23E9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23EA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23ED}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23EE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23EF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23F1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23F2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23F3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23F8}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23F9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{23FA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{25AA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{25AB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{25FB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{25FC}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{25FD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{25FE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2600}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2601}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2602}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2603}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2604}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2614}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2615}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2622}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2623}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{262E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{262F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2638}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2639}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{263A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2648}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2649}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{264A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{264B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{264C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{264D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{264E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{264F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2650}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2651}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2652}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2653}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2665}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2666}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2692}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2693}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2694}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2696}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2697}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{269B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{269C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26A0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26A1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26AA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26AB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26B0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26B1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26BD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26BE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26C4}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26C5}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26CF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26D3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26D4}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26E9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26EA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F4}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F5}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F7}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26F8}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{26FA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2708}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2709}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2733}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2734}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2753}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2763}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2764}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2934}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2935}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2B05}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2B06}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2B07}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2B1B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{2B1C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F170}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F171}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F17E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F17F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F1FC}[\u{1F1EB}\u{1F1F8}]?|\u{1F1FE}[\u{1F1EA}\u{1F1F9}]?|\u{1F202}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F237}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F30D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F30E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F30F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F315}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F31C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F321}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F324}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F325}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F326}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F327}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F328}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F329}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F32A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F32B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F32C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F336}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F378}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F37D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F393}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F396}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F397}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F399}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F39A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F39B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F39E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F39F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3A7}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3AC}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3AD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3AE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3C6}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3CD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3CE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3D4}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3D5}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3D6}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3D7}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3D8}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3D9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3DA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3DB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3DC}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3DD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3DE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3DF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3E0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3ED}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3F4}[\u{200D}\u{E0067}]?|\u{1F3F5}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F3F7}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F408}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F41F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F426}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F43F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F453}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F46A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F47D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4A3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4B0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4B3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4BB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4BF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4CB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4DA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4DF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4E4}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4E5}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4E6}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4EA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4EB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4EC}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4ED}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4F7}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4F9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4FA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4FB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F4FD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F508}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F50D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F512}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F513}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F549}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F54A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F550}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F551}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F552}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F553}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F554}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F555}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F556}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F557}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F558}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F559}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F55A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F55B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F55C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F55D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F55E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F55F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F560}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F561}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F562}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F563}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F564}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F565}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F566}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F567}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F56F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F570}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F573}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F576}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F577}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F578}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F579}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F58A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F58B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F58C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F58D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5B1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5B2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5C2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5C3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5C4}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5D1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5D2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5D3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5DC}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5DD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5DE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F5FA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F610}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F687}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F68D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F691}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F694}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F698}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6AD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6B2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6B9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6BA}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6BC}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6CB}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6CD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6CE}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6CF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6E0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6E1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6E2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6E3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6E4}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\u{1F6E5}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]?|\uA9[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\uAE[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{203C}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2049}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2122}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2139}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2328}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{23CF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{24C2}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{25B6}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{25C0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{260E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2611}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2618}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2620}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2626}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{262A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2640}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2642}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{265F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2660}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2663}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2668}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{267B}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{267E}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{267F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2695}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2699}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{26C8}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{26D1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{26FD}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2702}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{270F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2712}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2714}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2716}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{271D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2721}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2744}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2747}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2757}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{27A1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2B50}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{2B55}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{3030}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{303D}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{3297}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{3299}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F004}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F21A}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F22F}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F587}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5A5}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5A8}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5BC}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5E1}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5E3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5E8}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5EF}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F5F3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F6E9}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F6F0}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F6F3}[\u{FE0E}\u{FE0F}]|\u{1F1F4}\u{1F1F2}?|\u{1F1F6}\u{1F1E6}?|\u{1F1FD}\u{1F1F0}?|\u{1F46F}\u{200D}?|\u{1F93C}\u{200D}?|\u{1F9DE}\u{200D}?|\u{1F9DF}\u{200D}?)$/u
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, really helpful! However I can't seem to make your resulting regex work as it errors out anywhere I try it.