# How to verify if a string is ONLY ONE emoji?

Tags: javascript, regex, emoji

### The problem

With Javascript, I need to check if a string is an emoji.

### Should Return TRUE:

```js
REGEX.test("")    |    REGEX.test("")
REGEX.test("")    |    REGEX.test("")
REGEX.test("️‍♀️")    |    REGEX.test("")
REGEX.test("‍")    |    REGEX.test("")
REGEX.test("")    |    REGEX.test("")
```

- The string is ONE and ONLY ONE emoji, **not** 2 emojis, not one emoji and some number or special character or some letter, just ONE EMOJI.

### Should return FALSE:

```js
REGEX.test("")       |    REGEX.test("213")
REGEX.test(" adas")    |    REGEX.test("$@#*///")
REGEX.test("\/..")     |    REGEX.test("XD")
REGEX.test("   ‍   ")   |    REGEX.test(":D")
REGEX.test("♥︎")          |    REGEX.test("✹")
```

- The string contains more than one emoji
- The string has letters
- The string has a special character
- The string has anything that isn't an emoji.
- Symbols can't be matched.

## Maybe a path to the solution

I found [this regex](https://www.regextester.com/106421), which matches all the possible emotes, but I don't make any idea about how to make it fits in my case.

Comment: You just need to use a regex to match *all* emojis and use `^` and `$` anchors to make it match the whole string.

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew , how are you?

I believe it is a mistake to mark this issue as a duplicate.

To solve this specific problem, you need 2 other questions, not just one. It's okay that already have a similar question, the one about check for only one specific string, but it is not intuitive to be found when you are faced with the problem mentioned in this question.

I believe the issue is important for the community as a whole, mainly due to indexation issues.

Could you please think a little better about it, and if possible, remove the duplicate markup, please?

Comment: SO enabled several dupe reason support when closing questions as duplicates for a reason. Your question lacks efforts related to either matching an emoji or the entire string. The threads I closed with show exactly that: how to match an emoji and how to match the entire string. It is closed correctly.

Comment: Thanks for think about it. Although the way of solving the problems is the same, the questions aren't the same, but similar. There is a difference in that. This is a case-specific problem, and a generic issue can be more difficult to find when you are faced with this specific problem. So I will ask you once again to please rethink it. Marking this as a duplicate is a loss for the community, as the best thing about stack overflow is having all the answers to all the specific problems.

Comment: this closure was inappropriate. this is a JS question. the dup target is a C# question. if anything, the correct dup target is https://stackoverflow.com/q/58942139/11107541.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this function:

```js
function isOnlyOneEmoji(s) {
  var EmojiPattern = /^(?:\uD83D(?:\uDD73\uFE0F?|\uDC41(?:(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?)?|\u200D\uD83D\uDDE8\uFE0F?))?|[\uDDE8\uDDEF]\uFE0F?|\uDC4B(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDD90(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F))?|[\uDD96\uDC4C\uDC48\uDC49\uDC46\uDD95\uDC47\uDC4D\uDC4E\uDC4A\uDC4F\uDE4C\uDC50\uDE4F\uDC85\uDCAA\uDC42\uDC43\uDC76\uDC66\uDC67](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC71(?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2640\u2642]\uFE0F?)))?|\uDC68(?:(?:\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:\uD83E[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD]|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D(?:\uDC69\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|\uDC68\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?|[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92])|\u2708\uFE0F?|\u2764(?:\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D\uDC68|\uDC68)|\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D\uDC68|\uDC68)))))?|\uDC69(?:(?:\uD83C(?:\uDFFB(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC69\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF]|\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFC-\uDFFF])|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFC(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC69\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF]|\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFD-\uDFFF])|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFD(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC69\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF]|\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB\uDFFC\uDFFE\uDFFF])|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFE(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC69\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF]|\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFD\uDFFF])|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?|\uDFFF(?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC69\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE]|\uDC68\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFE])|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:\uD83E[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD]|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D(?:\uDC69\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?)|\uDC66(?:\u200D\uD83D\uDC66)?|\uDC67(?:\u200D\uD83D[\uDC66\uDC67])?|[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92])|\u2708\uFE0F?|\u2764(?:\uFE0F\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])|\u200D\uD83D(?:\uDC8B\u200D\uD83D[\uDC68\uDC69]|[\uDC68\uDC69])))))?|[\uDC74\uDC75](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDE4D\uDE4E\uDE45\uDE46\uDC81\uDE4B\uDE47\uDC6E](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|\uDD75(?:(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?|\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDC82\uDC77](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|\uDC78(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDC73(?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDC72\uDC70\uDC7C](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDC86\uDC87\uDEB6](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDC83\uDD7A](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDD74(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F))?|\uDC6F(?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?|[\uDEA3\uDEB4\uDEB5](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDEC0\uDECC\uDC6D\uDC6B\uDC6C](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDE3\uFE0F?|\uDC15(?:\u200D\uD83E\uDDBA)?|[\uDC3F\uDD4A\uDD77\uDD78\uDDFA\uDEE3\uDEE4\uDEE2\uDEF3\uDEE5\uDEE9\uDEF0\uDECE\uDD70\uDD79\uDDBC\uDD76\uDECD\uDDA5\uDDA8\uDDB1\uDDB2\uDCFD\uDD6F\uDDDE\uDDF3\uDD8B\uDD8A\uDD8C\uDD8D\uDDC2\uDDD2\uDDD3\uDD87\uDDC3\uDDC4\uDDD1\uDDDD\uDEE0\uDDE1\uDEE1\uDDDC\uDECF\uDECB\uDD49]\uFE0F?|[\uDE00\uDE03\uDE04\uDE01\uDE06\uDE05\uDE02\uDE42\uDE43\uDE09\uDE0A\uDE07\uDE0D\uDE18\uDE17\uDE1A\uDE19\uDE0B\uDE1B-\uDE1D\uDE10\uDE11\uDE36\uDE0F\uDE12\uDE44\uDE2C\uDE0C\uDE14\uDE2A\uDE34\uDE37\uDE35\uDE0E\uDE15\uDE1F\uDE41\uDE2E\uDE2F\uDE32\uDE33\uDE26-\uDE28\uDE30\uDE25\uDE22\uDE2D\uDE31\uDE16\uDE23\uDE1E\uDE13\uDE29\uDE2B\uDE24\uDE21\uDE20\uDE08\uDC7F\uDC80\uDCA9\uDC79-\uDC7B\uDC7D\uDC7E\uDE3A\uDE38\uDE39\uDE3B-\uDE3D\uDE40\uDE3F\uDE3E\uDE48-\uDE4A\uDC8B\uDC8C\uDC98\uDC9D\uDC96\uDC97\uDC93\uDC9E\uDC95\uDC9F\uDC94\uDC9B\uDC9A\uDC99\uDC9C\uDDA4\uDCAF\uDCA2\uDCA5\uDCAB\uDCA6\uDCA8\uDCA3\uDCAC\uDCAD\uDCA4\uDC40\uDC45\uDC44\uDC8F\uDC91\uDC6A\uDC64\uDC65\uDC63\uDC35\uDC12\uDC36\uDC29\uDC3A\uDC31\uDC08\uDC2F\uDC05\uDC06\uDC34\uDC0E\uDC2E\uDC02-\uDC04\uDC37\uDC16\uDC17\uDC3D\uDC0F\uDC11\uDC10\uDC2A\uDC2B\uDC18\uDC2D\uDC01\uDC00\uDC39\uDC30\uDC07\uDC3B\uDC28\uDC3C\uDC3E\uDC14\uDC13\uDC23-\uDC27\uDC38\uDC0A\uDC22\uDC0D\uDC32\uDC09\uDC33\uDC0B\uDC2C\uDC1F-\uDC21\uDC19\uDC1A\uDC0C\uDC1B-\uDC1E\uDC90\uDCAE\uDD2A\uDDFE\uDDFB\uDC92\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDD4C\uDED5\uDD4D\uDD4B\uDC88\uDE82-\uDE8A\uDE9D\uDE9E\uDE8B-\uDE8E\uDE90-\uDE9C\uDEF5\uDEFA\uDEB2\uDEF4\uDEF9\uDE8F\uDEA8\uDEA5\uDEA6\uDED1\uDEA7\uDEF6\uDEA4\uDEA2\uDEEB\uDEEC\uDCBA\uDE81\uDE9F-\uDEA1\uDE80\uDEF8\uDD5B\uDD67\uDD50\uDD5C\uDD51\uDD5D\uDD52\uDD5E\uDD53\uDD5F\uDD54\uDD60\uDD55\uDD61\uDD56\uDD62\uDD57\uDD63\uDD58\uDD64\uDD59\uDD65\uDD5A\uDD66\uDD25\uDCA7\uDEF7\uDD2E\uDC53-\uDC62\uDC51\uDC52\uDCFF\uDC84\uDC8D\uDC8E\uDD07-\uDD0A\uDCE2\uDCE3\uDCEF\uDD14\uDD15\uDCFB\uDCF1\uDCF2\uDCDE-\uDCE0\uDD0B\uDD0C\uDCBB\uDCBD-\uDCC0\uDCFA\uDCF7-\uDCF9\uDCFC\uDD0D\uDD0E\uDCA1\uDD26\uDCD4-\uDCDA\uDCD3\uDCD2\uDCC3\uDCDC\uDCC4\uDCF0\uDCD1\uDD16\uDCB0\uDCB4-\uDCB8\uDCB3\uDCB9\uDCB1\uDCB2\uDCE7-\uDCE9\uDCE4-\uDCE6\uDCEB\uDCEA\uDCEC-\uDCEE\uDCDD\uDCBC\uDCC1\uDCC2\uDCC5-\uDCD0\uDD12\uDD13\uDD0F-\uDD11\uDD28\uDD2B\uDD27\uDD29\uDD17\uDD2C\uDD2D\uDCE1\uDC89\uDC8A\uDEAA\uDEBD\uDEBF\uDEC1\uDED2\uDEAC\uDDFF\uDEAE\uDEB0\uDEB9-\uDEBC\uDEBE\uDEC2-\uDEC5\uDEB8\uDEAB\uDEB3\uDEAD\uDEAF\uDEB1\uDEB7\uDCF5\uDD1E\uDD03\uDD04\uDD19-\uDD1D\uDED0\uDD4E\uDD2F\uDD00-\uDD02\uDD3C\uDD3D\uDD05\uDD06\uDCF6\uDCF3\uDCF4\uDD31\uDCDB\uDD30\uDD1F-\uDD24\uDD34\uDFE0-\uDFE2\uDD35\uDFE3-\uDFE5\uDFE7-\uDFE9\uDFE6\uDFEA\uDFEB\uDD36-\uDD3B\uDCA0\uDD18\uDD33\uDD32\uDEA9])|\uD83E(?:[\uDD1A\uDD0F\uDD1E\uDD1F\uDD18\uDD19\uDD1B\uDD1C\uDD32\uDD33\uDDB5\uDDB6\uDDBB\uDDD2](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDDD1(?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:\uD83E(?:\uDD1D\u200D\uD83E\uDDD1|[\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDDAF\uDDBC\uDDBD])|\u2695\uFE0F?|\uD83C[\uDF93\uDFEB\uDF3E\uDF73\uDFED\uDFA4\uDFA8]|\u2696\uFE0F?|\uD83D[\uDD27\uDCBC\uDD2C\uDCBB\uDE80\uDE92]|\u2708\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDDD4\uDDD3](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDDCF\uDD26\uDD37](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDD34\uDDD5\uDD35\uDD30\uDD31\uDD36](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\uDDB8\uDDB9\uDDD9-\uDDDD](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDDDE\uDDDF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?|[\uDDCD\uDDCE\uDDD6\uDDD7\uDD38](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|\uDD3C(?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?|[\uDD3D\uDD3E\uDD39\uDDD8](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDD23\uDD70\uDD29\uDD2A\uDD11\uDD17\uDD2D\uDD2B\uDD14\uDD10\uDD28\uDD25\uDD24\uDD12\uDD15\uDD22\uDD2E\uDD27\uDD75\uDD76\uDD74\uDD2F\uDD20\uDD73\uDD13\uDDD0\uDD7A\uDD71\uDD2C\uDD21\uDD16\uDDE1\uDD0E\uDD0D\uDD1D\uDDBE\uDDBF\uDDE0\uDDB7\uDDB4\uDD3A\uDDB0\uDDB1\uDDB3\uDDB2\uDD8D\uDDA7\uDDAE\uDD8A\uDD9D\uDD81\uDD84\uDD93\uDD8C\uDD99\uDD92\uDD8F\uDD9B\uDD94\uDD87\uDDA5\uDDA6\uDDA8\uDD98\uDDA1\uDD83\uDD85\uDD86\uDDA2\uDD89\uDDA9\uDD9A\uDD9C\uDD8E\uDD95\uDD96\uDD88\uDD8B\uDD97\uDD82\uDD9F\uDDA0\uDD40\uDD6D\uDD5D\uDD65\uDD51\uDD54\uDD55\uDD52\uDD6C\uDD66\uDDC4\uDDC5\uDD5C\uDD50\uDD56\uDD68\uDD6F\uDD5E\uDDC7\uDDC0\uDD69\uDD53\uDD6A\uDD59\uDDC6\uDD5A\uDD58\uDD63\uDD57\uDDC8\uDDC2\uDD6B\uDD6E\uDD5F-\uDD61\uDD80\uDD9E\uDD90\uDD91\uDDAA\uDDC1\uDD67\uDD5B\uDD42\uDD43\uDD64\uDDC3\uDDC9\uDDCA\uDD62\uDD44\uDDED\uDDF1\uDDBD\uDDBC\uDE82\uDDF3\uDE90\uDDE8\uDDE7\uDD47-\uDD49\uDD4E\uDD4F\uDD4D\uDD4A\uDD4B\uDD45\uDD3F\uDD4C\uDE80\uDE81\uDDFF\uDDE9\uDDF8\uDDF5\uDDF6\uDD7D\uDD7C\uDDBA\uDDE3-\uDDE6\uDD7B\uDE71-\uDE73\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDE70\uDDE2\uDE95\uDD41\uDDEE\uDE94\uDDFE\uDE93\uDDAF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDE78-\uDE7A\uDE91\uDE92\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9-\uDDFD\uDDEF])|[\u263A\u2639\u2620\u2763\u2764]\uFE0F?|\u270B(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|[\u270C\u261D](?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F))?|\u270A(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\u270D(?:(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF]|\uFE0F))?|\uD83C(?:\uDF85(?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDFC3(?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDFC7\uDFC2](?:\uD83C[\uDFFB-\uDFFF])?|\uDFCC(?:(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?|\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDFC4\uDFCA](?:(?:\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|\uDFCB(?:(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?|\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\uDFF5\uDF36\uDF7D\uDFD4-\uDFD6\uDFDC-\uDFDF\uDFDB\uDFD7\uDFD8\uDFDA\uDFD9\uDFCE\uDFCD\uDF21\uDF24-\uDF2C\uDF97\uDF9F\uDF96\uDF99-\uDF9B\uDF9E\uDFF7\uDD70\uDD71\uDD7E\uDD7F\uDE02\uDE37]\uFE0F?|\uDFF4(?:(?:\u200D\u2620\uFE0F?|\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC62\uDB40(?:\uDC65\uDB40\uDC6E\uDB40\uDC67\uDB40\uDC7F|\uDC73\uDB40\uDC63\uDB40\uDC74\uDB40\uDC7F|\uDC77\uDB40\uDC6C\uDB40\uDC73\uDB40\uDC7F)))?|\uDFF3(?:(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D\uD83C\uDF08)?|\u200D\uD83C\uDF08))?|\uDDE6\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFD\uDDFF]|\uDDE7\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEF\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDE8\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDEE\uDDF0-\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA-\uDDFF]|\uDDE9\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEF\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDFF]|\uDDEA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDED\uDDF7-\uDDFA]|\uDDEB\uD83C[\uDDEE-\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF7]|\uDDEC\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE7\uDDE9-\uDDEE\uDDF1-\uDDF3\uDDF5-\uDDFA\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDED\uD83C[\uDDF0\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFA]|\uDDEE\uD83C[\uDDE8-\uDDEA\uDDF1-\uDDF4\uDDF6-\uDDF9]|\uDDEF\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF2\uDDF4\uDDF5]|\uDDF0\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDEE\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFC\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDF1\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDE8\uDDEE\uDDF0\uDDF7-\uDDFB\uDDFE]|\uDDF2\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDFF]|\uDDF3\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA-\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF1\uDDF4\uDDF5\uDDF7\uDDFA\uDDFF]|\uDDF4\uD83C\uDDF2|\uDDF5\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEA-\uDDED\uDDF0-\uDDF3\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFC\uDDFE]|\uDDF6\uD83C\uDDE6|\uDDF7\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF4\uDDF8\uDDFA\uDDFC]|\uDDF8\uD83C[\uDDE6-\uDDEA\uDDEC-\uDDF4\uDDF7-\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFD-\uDDFF]|\uDDF9\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDE9\uDDEB-\uDDED\uDDEF-\uDDF4\uDDF7\uDDF9\uDDFB\uDDFC\uDDFF]|\uDDFA\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDEC\uDDF2\uDDF3\uDDF8\uDDFE\uDDFF]|\uDDFB\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDE8\uDDEA\uDDEC\uDDEE\uDDF3\uDDFA]|\uDDFC\uD83C[\uDDEB\uDDF8]|\uDDFD\uD83C\uDDF0|\uDDFE\uD83C[\uDDEA\uDDF9]|\uDDFF\uD83C[\uDDE6\uDDF2\uDDFC]|[\uDFFB-\uDFFF\uDF38-\uDF3C\uDF37\uDF31-\uDF35\uDF3E-\uDF43\uDF47-\uDF53\uDF45\uDF46\uDF3D\uDF44\uDF30\uDF5E\uDF56\uDF57\uDF54\uDF5F\uDF55\uDF2D-\uDF2F\uDF73\uDF72\uDF7F\uDF71\uDF58-\uDF5D\uDF60\uDF62-\uDF65\uDF61\uDF66-\uDF6A\uDF82\uDF70\uDF6B-\uDF6F\uDF7C\uDF75\uDF76\uDF7E\uDF77-\uDF7B\uDF74\uDFFA\uDF0D-\uDF10\uDF0B\uDFE0-\uDFE6\uDFE8-\uDFED\uDFEF\uDFF0\uDF01\uDF03-\uDF07\uDF09\uDFA0-\uDFA2\uDFAA\uDF11-\uDF20\uDF0C\uDF00\uDF08\uDF02\uDF0A\uDF83\uDF84\uDF86-\uDF8B\uDF8D-\uDF91\uDF80\uDF81\uDFAB\uDFC6\uDFC5\uDFC0\uDFD0\uDFC8\uDFC9\uDFBE\uDFB3\uDFCF\uDFD1-\uDFD3\uDFF8\uDFA3\uDFBD\uDFBF\uDFAF\uDFB1\uDFAE\uDFB0\uDFB2\uDCCF\uDC04\uDFB4\uDFAD\uDFA8\uDF92\uDFA9\uDF93\uDFBC\uDFB5\uDFB6\uDFA4\uDFA7\uDFB7-\uDFBB\uDFA5\uDFAC\uDFEE\uDFF9\uDFE7\uDFA6\uDD8E\uDD91-\uDD9A\uDE01\uDE36\uDE2F\uDE50\uDE39\uDE1A\uDE32\uDE51\uDE38\uDE34\uDE33\uDE3A\uDE35\uDFC1\uDF8C])|\u26F7\uFE0F?|\u26F9(?:(?:\uFE0F(?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?|\uD83C(?:[\uDFFB-\uDFFF](?:\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?))?)|\u200D(?:[\u2642\u2640]\uFE0F?)))?|[\u2618\u26F0\u26E9\u2668\u26F4\u2708\u23F1\u23F2\u2600\u2601\u26C8\u2602\u26F1\u2744\u2603\u2604\u26F8\u2660\u2665\u2666\u2663\u265F\u26D1\u260E\u2328\u2709\u270F\u2712\u2702\u26CF\u2692\u2694\u2699\u2696\u26D3\u2697\u26B0\u26B1\u26A0\u2622\u2623\u2B06\u2197\u27A1\u2198\u2B07\u2199\u2B05\u2196\u2195\u2194\u21A9\u21AA\u2934\u2935\u269B\u2721\u2638\u262F\u271D\u2626\u262A\u262E\u25B6\u23ED\u23EF\u25C0\u23EE\u23F8-\u23FA\u23CF\u2640\u2642\u2695\u267E\u267B\u269C\u2611\u2714\u2716\u303D\u2733\u2734\u2747\u203C\u2049\u3030\u00A9\u00AE\u2122]\uFE0F?|[\u0023\u002A\u0030-\u0039](?:\uFE0F\u20E3|\u20E3)|[\u2139\u24C2\u3297\u3299\u25FC\u25FB\u25AA\u25AB]\uFE0F?|[\u2615\u26EA\u26F2\u26FA\u26FD\u2693\u26F5\u231B\u23F3\u231A\u23F0\u2B50\u26C5\u2614\u26A1\u26C4\u2728\u26BD\u26BE\u26F3\u267F\u26D4\u2648-\u2653\u26CE\u23E9-\u23EC\u2B55\u2705\u274C\u274E\u2795-\u2797\u27B0\u27BF\u2753-\u2755\u2757\u26AB\u26AA\u2B1B\u2B1C\u25FE\u25FD])$/;
  return EmojiPattern.test(s);
}


console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("️‍♀️")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("‍")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 

console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji(" adas")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("\/..")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("  ‍   ")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("213")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("$@#*///")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("XD")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("♥︎")); 
console.log(isOnlyOneEmoji("✹"));
```

Comment: It's almost it! :D
The "♥︎" symbol cannot be matched.
Sorry, I forgot to add the symbols in the "Should return FALSE" section.

Comment: check my updated example the  "♥︎" symbol  is not matched